# Incorrect Scaling when converting from excel to pdf using PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, tcpdf, dompdf, mpdf, phpspreadsheet

I have an excel template the I am filling with PhpSpreadsheet, which works flawlessly. However, when I try to then save it as a pdf, the scaling is wrong and the content does not fit on the page. I have tried using Tcpdf, Mpdf, and Dompdf, all with similar results. Mpdf has given the closest output so far, however the scaling is still incorrect.

I have tried setting the margins (that seems to have no effect), as well as setting FitToPage, FitToWidth and FitToHeight to true.

Any ideas on what how to fix it? Ideally, I would like to use Tcpdf, as I am using it for other purposes.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
// XLSX
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load(THIS_LIB_PATH_UP.'templates/1/rent2.xlsx');
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->getPageMargins()
    ->setLeft(0)
    ->setRight(0)
    ->setTop(0)
    ->setBottom(0)
    ->setHeader(0)
        ->setFooter(0);
$sheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToWidth(1);
$sheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToHeight(1);
$sheet->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);
$sheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToPage(true);
// Date 
$sheet->setCellValue('F4', date('d-m-Y'));
// Receipt Number 
$sheet->setCellValue('F6', 'Receipt No. '.rand(0,100));
// FROM
$sheet->setCellValue('B10', 'Owner');
$sheet->setCellValue('B11', 'The');
$sheet->setCellValue('B12', 'Address');
$sheet->setCellValue('B13', 'Mobile');
$sheet->setCellValue('B14', 'email@email.com');
// TO
$sheet->setCellValue('D10', 'Tenant');
$sheet->setCellValue('D11', 'Address');
$sheet->setCellValue('D12', 'email@email.com');
$sheet->setCellValue('D13', 'Mobile');
// Description / Total
$sheet->setCellValue('B20', "Rent");
$sheet->setCellValue('F20', rand(0,500));
// Payment Method 
$sheet->setCellValue('C34', 'Bank Transfer');
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$filename = THIS_LIB_PATH_UP.'templates/1/'.date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');
$writer->save($filename.'.xlsx');

// Open the xlsx file for pdf export
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Tcpdf');
$writer->save($filename.'.pdf');
echo 'Done';
```

**Excel Template**  [image: Excel Template]

**Directly exported** [image: Directly exported]

[TcPDF output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jDIi.png) **Badly cropped and thick blocky linework**

[DomPDF Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1bDb.png) **Best result, but is not rescaling to page width**

[Mpdf Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCLPq.png) **Re-scales width but has other issues such as no logo**

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @KJ - Thanks for the formatting help. For your suggestion, might you be able to point me to some example DomPDF code for this? Cheers!